# Is a .Net Lock(context) atomic?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking, atomic

I do understand that a .net lock ensures that only a single thread performs the lines of code found within the scope of the lock.

What I don't understand is whether a lock is atomic. 
Can a thread be interrupted while performing the locked code?

For example - It appears to me that if a lock is NOT atomic, then the following code is not thread safe:

```
Class example
{
  private int myNumber;
  private object context = new object();

 void Write()
 {
    myNumber--;
 }

 void WriteLock()
 {
     lock (context)
     {
        myNumber++;
        print(myNumber);
     }
 }
```

}

If thread A peforms method WriteLock() and is interrupted because thread B is performing Write(), then myNumber may be changed unsafely. Am I right?

Comment: Why not trying it out in multi-threaded environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's quacks loudly like a bug.  Those operators are not atomic, even though they look like it.  Under the hood, they operate as a read-modify-write, three operations instead of one.  So are themselves not atomic.  The missing lock in Write() permits it to execute concurrently with WriteLock().  The outcome is arbitrary, including no change when Write races ahead of WriteLock and the value actually getting decremented when WriteLock races ahead of Write.

Having a thread interrupted while it owns the lock doesn't matter, the lock just will be held longer.

Use Interlocked.Increment() and Decrement() for a cheaper version that doesn't need *lock*.

Answer (score 1):

Check the msdn documentation. I would imagine that it is either atomic or is implementing some other pattern to ensure this cannot happen.

The issue with your example is that the Write method should also be obtaining a lock before decrementing myNumber so that no other thread can alter the shared resource.

```
void Write()
{
  lock(context) {
    myNumber--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Dave. I don't think that an additional lock solved my problem. What if a thread is interrupted while conducting this lock's code?

Comment: You have to obtain a lock before altering any shared resource. Because you are not obtaining a lock on the context object before decrementing myNumber you are allowing other threads the opportunity to decrement myNumber while thread A in you example is in the critical section.
Lock only prevents a thread accessing that section of code and not the shared resource in general.

Comment: [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) 
[Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf5de04k.aspx)

Comment: Dave - You were right about the additional lock you had mentioned, it had just taken me some time to understand your point. Thanks for your answer :)